# Space between titles and text

Tags: formatting

I need to fix the space between some titles and text in my dissertation. The correct space is the one you can see in the "Resumo" page. Every other space (for example, between a section and text, subsection and text, subsubsection and text, or as you can see in the figure between "Agradecimentos" and text) is wrong.

The red lines I drew indicate the size difference.

Here's a mwe of my code.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    oneside,                % para impressão apenas em verso.
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel.
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    subsection=title,   % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras minúsculas
    subsubsection=title,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras minúsculas
    brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

\begin{document}

\begin{agradecimentos}

Wrong space here!

\end{agradecimentos}


\begin{resumo}[Resumo]

Correct space here!

\vspace{\onelineskip}

\textbf{Palavras-chave}: abstract, help.

\end{resumo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you need to set all section and chapter spaces to 1 line. There are some packages and classes that do that.  You should take a look at the `abntex2` class documentation, the class itself (it's on github, CTAN and there's a site, too) and perhaps at the memoir documentation (`abntex2` is based on `memoir`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `memoir` class (`memoir` documentation, 6.5, p. 85):

```
\documentclass{abntex2} % só para simplificar, outros fatores irrelevantes
\usepackage{mwe} % para lipsum etc. p/ ex. 

% A norma não diz nada sobre identação e separação entre parágrafos no abstract,
% porém o uso mostra que muitos abstracts são montados sem identação.
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \setlength{\absparindent}{\parindent}
}


\renewcommand*{\afterchapskip}{1ex} % <<<< mude ao seu gosto

\begin{document}

\begin{agradecimentos}

Veja o espaçamento aqui. Ficou bom?

\end{agradecimentos}

teste

teste para mostrar que não precisa de indentfirst

teste


\begin{resumo} % o resumo já fica com o nome de resumo


\lipsum[1-3]


\vspace{\onelineskip}

\textbf{Palavras-chave}: LaTeX, tipografia, pinga com torresmo.

\end{resumo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, so simple... Thanks!